# "TypeError: require(...) is not a constructor" in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I'm trying to create a new version of my Discord bot in discord.js v13. For this, I'm using TypeScript and I'm creating a class for my Client who extends `Discord.Client`. In my custom class, I add an async function for load commands from the Commands folder. My commands are class like this:

```
import { Message } from "discord.js";
import { HeavensBot } from "../HeavensBot";
import { Command as Base } from "../util/Base";

export class Ping extends Base {
    constructor(client: HeavensBot) {
        super(client, {
            name: "ping",
            description: "Ping command",
            aliases: [],
        });
    }

    run(message: Message, args: string[]) {
        const start = Date.now();

        message.reply({
            content: `Pong! Took ${Date.now() - start}ms`,
        });
    }
}
```

But, I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: require(...) is not a constructor

How to correct it?

My `loadCommands` function:

```
async loadCommands(): Promise<void> {
    fs.readdir("./Commands", (err, files) => {
      if(err) throw err;

      files.forEach((file) => {
        const command = new(require(`./Commands/${file.replace(".ts", "")}`));

        this.commands.set(command.help.name, command);

        command.conf.aliases.forEach((aliase: string) => this.aliases.set(aliase, command.help.name))
      });
    });
  }
```

My Base class:

```
import { HeavensBot } from "../HeavensBot";

interface CommandOptions {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    aliases: string[];
}

interface CommandDotHelp {
    name: string;
    description: string;
}

interface Configuration {
    aliases: string[];
}

export class Command {
    private client: HeavensBot;
    private help: CommandDotHelp;
    private conf: Configuration;

    constructor(client: HeavensBot, options: CommandOptions) {
        this.client = client;
        this.help = {
            name: options.name,
            description: options.description,
        }
        this.conf = {
            aliases: options.aliases,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `new (require(...).default)` (you are missing `.default`, you want to access your default export I assume)

Comment: @CherryDT yes, but they will also need to export the classes as default too

Comment: Oops I thought that was the case. Then it'd be `new (require(...).Ping)` - which doesn't scale, so the right way would be to make `export class Ping` actually `export default class Ping` as you said

Comment: So i need to replace `export class Ping` by `export default class Ping`?

Comment: that works, thanks